# Why is my model always displaying the same output for each user's input?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I am trying do make a self diagnosis application. The problem is that each time a user selects the symptoms, the disease will always be 'Tuberculosis' (it is the disease with the largest number of symptoms from the dataset)

For this app, I am using this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/itachi9604/disease-symptom-description-dataset?select=dataset.csv)
I trained the model like this, with DecisionTreeClassifier:

```
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

# Remove unwanted spaces (as some cells have a space in front)
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)

# fill the empty values with "unknown"
data = data.fillna("unknown")

# Split the dataset into features (symptoms) and target (disease)
X = data.drop(columns=["Disease"])
y = data["Disease"]

# Encode categorical variables using ordinal encoding
encoder = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1)
X_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(X)

# Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train a random forest classifier, as it gave me the best accuracy score (0.94)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=5, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate the model on the testing set
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pr = clf.predict(X_encoded)

accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=1, average='weighted')
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=1, average='weighted')
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, zero_division=1, average='weighted')
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}, Precision: {precision}, Recall: {recall}, F1-score: {f1}")

# Save the trained model to a file
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.joblib')
joblib.dump(encoder, 'encoder.joblib')
```

I also have a function (I think that the problem comes from here), which should handle a user input, a list of symptoms. It looks like this:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    clf = joblib.load('model.joblib')
    encoder = joblib.load('encoder.joblib')
    symptoms = request.get_json()['symptoms']

    # if the length of array is smaller than 17, add -1 for unknown value
    # otherwise I get the error: ValueError: X has 1 features, but OrdinalEncoder is expecting 17 features as input.
    # as there are 17 columns of symptoms

    # while len(symptoms) != 17:
    #     symptoms.append(-1)

    symptoms_encoded = encoder.transform([symptoms])
    disease = clf.predict(symptoms_encoded)[0]
    return jsonify({'disease': disease})
```

Comment: I think you should fix your activation function. Because it seems like your neurons outputs are incorrect. Or maybe there's problems with back propagations and derivatives...